# Windows 7 OEM license on Macbook?

Tags: windows-7, license

A lot of sellers offer OEM licenses with COA stickers on [ebay](http://www.ebay.com/itm/Latest-Microsoft-Windows-7-Home-Premium-32-Or-64-Bit-Coa-Activation-Key-/131304915547?pt=UK_Computing_Software_Software_SR&hash=item1e9262025b).
Assuming that license and sticker are genuine and lic key was never activated, would it be 100% legal if I buy one and use on my Macbook Pro?

If I understand OEM license correctly, OEM means that it's PREINSTALLED on some hardware and bound to it forever. So how can it be legally transferred to another hardware (my mac)?

Comment: Sorry, OEM of course. There is no such thing as EOM Windows license.

Comment: *"Assuming that license ... key was never activated"*  -- Why would you ever assume that? At the bottom of that eBay web page, there's a disclaimer that states: *"We will physically post the hardware along with the software to buyers Therefore, we sell these items bundled with the **original broken system motherboard**."*  *"So how can it be legally transferred to another hardware (my mac)?"* -- IMO it cannot.  That's why it's a lot cheaper than an unopened OEM System Builder package.

Comment: Your comment seems to actually answer my question.

At the moment I was posting, I did not know anything about OEM System Builder. It seems that unopened System Builder is exactly what I'm looking for, right?

Answer (score 0):

Legally, no. However, I've talked to Microsoft when I worked in a computer shop, and was told they do not care whether a customer buys OEM (original equipment manufacturer) licensing, or retail.

Once OEM is installed, it is legally bound to that hardware. This means you can't legally move it to another computer, even if the first one dies. Retail allows you to move to another computer after the first one dies. I'm my experience though, Microsoft does not mind OEM being moved to another system if it's only done once. They may change their mind soon, but only they could tell you.

Comment: Your answer seems to be for "OEM System Builder" license.  The eBay link in the OP is for a ***recycled*** OEM license.  At the bottom of the page is a disclaimer that states: *"We will physically post the hardware along with the software to buyers Therefore, we sell these items bundled with the **original broken system motherboard**."*

Comment: @sawdust OEM still belongs on the physical hardware it was sold with, whether it be virtual or directly. Moving it between different computers is *technically* not allowed with any OEM license. If you can find definitive proof otherwise, I'll retract my statement

Comment: My original comment is poorly composed.  I was referring to your *" they do not care whether a customer buys OEM (...) licensing, or retail"*.  You seem to be referring to an unused  "OEM System Builder package".  The OP is asking about an OEM license that seems to already have been activated.

Comment: They don't say whether it has been activated or not. The OPK (OEM Pre-installed Key) is a generic key for each manufacturer so they can image thousands of PCs at once with a genuine key. There are lots of OEM keys (where the actual sticker comes into play) that are not used, but they are still licensed only for that PHYSICAL system. If the license was already activated, it may work, but it may not, depending on how close the hardware is to the original configuration